# How to ignore node_modules recursively in Dropbox on a Mac

Tags: node.js, npm, dropbox

I want to keep all my node projects saved in Dropbox except I want to exclude all `node_modules` directories from being synced to Dropbox.

I used to accomplish this by keeping these directories symlinked in a different location but recent versions of npm have broken the ability to do this by not allowing `npm_modules` to be a symlink.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following command will find and add all top-level node_module directories from Dropbox.  That is to say that it will add `node_module` directories but not `node_module` directories somewhere inside of another `node_modules` directory (because the top-level directory will already be ignored.

```
find ~/Dropbox  -type d | grep 'node_modules$' | grep -v '/node_modules/' | xargs -I {} -t -L 1 xattr -w com.dropbox.ignored 1 "{}"
```

Command breakdown:

- find all directories in `~/Dropbox`
- use `grep` to filter to only the directories that end in `node_modules`
- use `grep` to exclude from these directories that also include `node_modules/` **
- use `xargs` to pass this directory as an argument
- to the `xattr` command to tell dropbox to ignore it

** *If a directory ends with `node_modules` but also includes `node_modules/` then that directory is contained in a higher level `node_modules` directory so we can skip it because we will already be ignoring the higher level directory.*

---

Thanks to @shuckster for the following suggestion that eliminates the extra grep steps:

The `-prune` find option can perform the above task more quickly than the two grep pipes:

```
find ~/Dropbox -name node_modules -prune | xargs -I {} -t -L 1 xattr -w com.dropbox.ignored 1 "{}"
```

The full command [explained here](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=find+%7E%2FDropbox+-name+node_modules+-prune+%7C+xargs+-I+%7B%7D+-t+-L+1+xattr+-w+com.dropbox.ignored+1+%22%7B%7D%22).

---

Thanks to @shuckster for the following bash function that will automatically do run this after an npm install

Also, I have found it helpful to create a function in my `.bashrc` for `npm` that performs the permissions-update after an installation:

```
npm() {
  case "$1" in
    "install"|"i"|"ci")
      command npm "$@"

      if [[ $? -eq 0 && -d ./node_modules ]]; then
        xattr -w com.dropbox.ignored 1 ./node_modules
        echo "Added Dropbox-ignore permission to node_modules"
      fi
      ;;
    *)
      command npm "$@"
      ;;
  esac
}
```

Comment: The `xattr` this is really useful. Found [this guide](https://help.dropbox.com/files-folders/restore-delete/ignored-files)