# How can I get Dropbox (on Mac) to always ignore node_modules?

Tags: node.js, macos, dropbox

I am using Dropbox for everything and it works perfectly — except from with projects including node_modules where it fucks everything up.

I have tried different solutions, and have a terminal shortcut "di" to tell dropbox to ignore the node_modules-folder etc.
Sometime I forget running this, or the folder exists for long enough to put Dropbox in complete meltdown syncing 23,321,676,243,588,742 files.

I cannot see a single important usecase where I would need Dropbox to sync a folder named node_modules.
How can I make it ALWAYS ignore all folders named node_modules, or in another way avoid these kinds of syncing problems?

Comment: There is a script you can use to specifically address node_modules over on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69655522/how-to-ignore-node-modules-recursively-in-dropbox-on-a-mac/69655523#69655523

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done a quick Google search for you, since I've been looking for the same thing.

There is an answer on the similar/same question on superuser: https://superuser.com/a/1527145

And a comment to that answer by https://superuser.com/users/693355/panagiotis-simakis where he introduces his shell scriptthat utilizes files similar to `.gitignore` but for dropbox. Give it a try https://github.com/sp1thas/dropboxignore

Let me know if it works!

Comment: Thank you!
I tried it. Felt horrible sudo-installing something unknown like this, but it seems to have worked so far. Hopefully the sync issues is a thing of the past now.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you for trying it out for both of us!